# Merge duplicate edges and vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, faces

I have a model imported from SMD file, and all the faces of the mesh seem independent. When I move a single face, the faces around it do not warp (a hole appear in the mesh).

I wonder how I could make a unified mesh from all the independent faces ?

Thanks

Comment: Use W > Remove_Doubles